# What's the first mention of امّان and سومالی in Persian texts?

Tags: language, names

I am Iranian. As you know the country has been influenced very much by Islam and Arabic language since the conquer of Sassanid Empire by Muslim Arabs. Even the Persian alphabet wasn't prone to the influence and it greatly Arabicized. There are just four extra letters that aren't there in Arabic.

People of Iran use so many borrowed Arabic words very much in their everyday life; and none of these words are misspelled in Iran. All of them are written like their Arabic words (like صحرا which means desert). We only write ت instead of ة (both having the same sound) because we don't have the latter letter in our Alphabet (of course ت is in Arabic too).

But I am surprised by the case of امّان and سومالی. The former is the Capital City of Jordan which Arabs write it as عمّان (the strange thing is that both Arabic and Persian alphabets have ا and ع which produce the same sound). The latter word is the name of the country Somalia which Arabs write as صومال (again, both Arabic and Persian alphabets do have س and ص which produce the /s/ sound).

**Question**: What are the first recorded mentions of امّان and سومالی in Persian texts?

**Note**: The sign above م in امّان is important. Because the /m/ sound should be hard like in Ammonia. Without the sign the meaning of the word is changed (امان means security in Persian and Arabic). Of course, you can exclude the sign from the word; but then you have to add اردن (the Arabic and Persian words for Jordan) after it to mean the capital of the country. Also, there is another country called Oman (عُمان in both Persian and Arabic).

Comment: How about اتیوپی and إثيوبيا, or even closer to home تاجیکستان and طاجيكستان ?  It's a good question - though personally, I'd be more surprised if any of these words was actually Arabic in origin. I wonder if there are any Persian words of Arabic origin that are spelled differently.

Comment: @EtackSxchange, please don't comment; update the question.

Comment: Questions where OP replies in comments are more likely to be closed and less likely to receive an answer.  If you want an answer, best practice is to edit replies into the question.  Feel free to edit/revert.

Comment: Alif and ayn (mentioned in an earlier version of the question) are not the same in Arabic - they might be the same sound in certain Arabic dialects and in Persian, but historically they meant different sounds. Same might be true for some consonants (like those for k/q, t, s).

Comment: @Juhasz I know تاجیک has Turkic origin